# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device when installing deeppavlov model in docker container on Win 10

Tags: docker, wsl-2, deeppavlov

I'm trying to install a deeppavlov model on Windows 10 in a Docker container by running in Windows PowerShell:

```
docker run -e CONFIG=gobot_dstc2_best -p 5555:5000 -v ~/my_dp_components:/root/.deeppavlov -v ~/my_dp_envs:/venv deeppavlov/base-cpu
```

However, after downloading about 5Gb out of 8, it exits with an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

As far as I understand, there's something wrong with the space on the virtual disks in:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx
```

and

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro\ext4.vhdx
```

I tried to expand the space there using `diskpart`.
But when I checked the `ext4.vhdx` disk in the `data` folder for details, it said it had
`Virtual space: 256 Gb` and `Physical space: 4667 Mb`
Could anyone explain please what's going on here? Maybe I'm searching in the wrong directory? I don't get it why there's not enough space :(

Comment: Hi! Maybe you don't have enough space on the actual drive? I know this sounds a bit silly but might be a problem if your C: drive is on SSD and that one is too small.

Comment: @DanielKornev I have enough free space, so I don't think that's the issue... :( I tried installing it on Ubuntu after this, and it worked. Doesn't work like this for Windows, though :(